# How to set up a zookeeper quorum?

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2

I have an issue with the below given statement. I haven't tried executing the statement as I didn't understand what is this used for

What should I pass as arguments for server.1, zoo1

```
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888     
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

What does the above statement mean

What values should I pass and what is the above statement used for

Can u explain with an example

I have a cluster of 4 computers with high availability enabled

```
Machine 1 and 2 - Zookeeper, zkfc, Namenode, Resourcemanager, Journal node
Machine3 - Zookepper, Journal node
Machine4 - Datanode
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These entries define the quorum of Zookeeper servers.

```
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888     
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

And they follow the pattern,

```
server.X=server_name:port1:port2
```

`server.X`, where `X` is the server number in ASCII. Create a file named as `myid` under the Zookeeper data directory in each Zookeeper server. This file should contain the server number `X` as an entry in it.

`server_name` is the `hostname` of the node where the Zookeeper service is started.

`port1`, ZooKeeper server uses this port to connect followers to the leader.

`port2`, this port is used for leader election.

> When a new leader arises, a follower opens a TCP connection to the
>   leader using this port. Because the default leader election also uses
>   TCP, we currently require another port for leader election. This is
>   the second port in the server entry.